# Why isn't my account sharing rule showing the opportunities?

Tags: force.com, sharing

Can someone explain the account sharing interface to me in terms of the opportunity and case access? I thought this would let you set sharing rules for opps.

Problem:

I'm trying to make opportunities r/w for a group of users. The way I went about it off of the **account sharing rule page** which lets you set access to other objects .  I made the settings below, and after the rule calculates, the users in group Test aren't able to access the opportunities.  I had to go and create a second sharing rule in opportunities.

Setup:

```
//Sharing rule set up:
Account: owned by members of: Group: Test Share with Group: Test
Default Account, Contract and Asset Access - Read / Write
Opportunity Access - Read/ Write
Case Access - Read / Write


//Org Wide Defaults
Account and Opp = Private
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the answer is that the owner of the records were not assigned to a role. as a result they fall out of the sharing rules!

Ugh!